# Mongoose: Using $addFields, $filter and $map inside deeply nested array in mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoose schema that is structured like this:

```msql
Schema E = {
    _id,
    ... some fields,
    details: [
       {
          ...somefields,
          people: [ObjectIds] 
       }
    ]
}
```

First, I have an aggregate query where I am using *$geoNear then $match, and then $facet*.
After the operations the document that I get is as follows:

```msql
estates: [
    {
       _id,
       ... some fields,
       details: [
          {
             ...somefields,
             people: [ObjectIds]
          }
       ],
       ... other fields
    },
    ... more estate objects
]
],
page: [...some objects]
```

I have an array called **approved** which has some object Ids.

I want to filter the **page** array inside **events.details** while keeping the rest of the fields intact.

The result I want is as follows:

**NOTE**: *The field **filteredPeople** is the array I want after filtering **people** with **approved**.

```msql
estate: [
    {
       _id,
       ... some fields,
       details: [
          {
             ...somefields,
             filteredPeople: [ObjectIds],
             numberOfPeople: Size of people array

          }
       ],
       ... other fields
    },
    ... more estate objectes
],
page: [...some objects]
```

This is what I tried doing:

```msql
{
  "estates": {
  "$map": {
    "input": "$estates",
    "as": "estate",
    "in": {
      "details": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$$estate.details",
          "as": "detail",
          "in": {
            "filteredPeople": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$$detail.people",
                "as": "people",
                "cond": { "$in": ["$$people", approved] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  },
}
```

But this erases the other fields. The other way is to create a separate field called estatePeople where the result of the `$addFields` will be stored.

I could then try to merge the two arrays. But I don't have any field to match them as the second estatePoeple array will not have anything but the filteredPeople. So I will then somehow have to merge the two arrays just by the index of the array and where they appear.

Can someone please help me out on how to get the desired document with relatively good performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has the same problem:
In the end, I was unable to find any way to execute the query that I wanted with reasonable performance.

This *schema design is not the optimal* way to execute such complicated queries. What I ended up doing was *making the details array an object* and have separate documents for separate details. And then I made a *parent schema* that kept reference of the details for the same estate.

You can use reverse referencing or referencing according to the queries that you want to execute.